# (Xpages) SOA or Direct Database Access

Tags: data-binding, rdbms, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages

I'm currently doing an application usign Lotus Notes' XPages. I'm planning to use XPages(or Lotus Notes in general) as the front-end/UI/Design only (not a data storage), while an RDBMS (Oracle, MySQL) as the data storage. I found out that XPages currently doesn't support external RDBMS as data source. Based on my research, I have 2 options (or if you know of others, please put it in the comment section), either to so a SOA approach (where I will get my data using web services) or a direct access to the database (using a Java to RDBMS connector library) that I will wrap in XAgents. I don't want this question to be subjective, so I will just ask what are the pros and cons if using the approaches. I'm for speed and data reliability. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: It is possible to connect to a relational data source. http://blog.sequill.com/2011/02/xpages-data-source-control-for-relational-databases/

Answer (score 2):

Why not consider using Extension Library? http://extlib.openntf.org/

This is a collaboration between developers on OpenNTF and IBM. Dead easy to install and has RDBMS support.

Answer (score 0):

I second the XPages Extension Library approach. The code is there and even takes advantage of session pooling. Just make sure you don't design an SQL injection attack vector. Of course you could consider DECS / LEI too