# ODBC to Lotus Notes

Tags: odbc, lotus-notes

In an xpage I would like to import data from another server and system with odbc (to a Lotus Notes View)
How could I do this ?

(NotesSQL does as far as I understand the opposite)

I guess I need to install DECS.
but then in the help file I found :

> To load the DECS server task, the real-time extension manager library variable must be set in the notes.ini file

Domino is running on a linux server. What's my library variable then ?

Comment: Normally you would use a direct Domino to Domino connection and not consider something like ODBC. Is there a reason you can't do this here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think DECS has much to do with this, particularly since you are talking about XPages.  As suggested in these two previously-answered questions, you should probably be using the OpenNTF Extension Library:

- [Lotus Notes XPages for design and Oracle (or other RDBMS) for
  data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401025/lotus-notes-xpages-for-design-and-oracle-or-other-rdbms-for-data)
- [(Xpages) SOA or Direct Database Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414822/xpages-soa-or-direct-database-access)